# CentOS 7 - gnome 3 - customise "Applications" logo

Tags: linux, icons, redhat, centos7, gnome-3

In CentOS 7 - on gnome 3 there is a small CentOS icon to the left of the "Applications" menu option. I would like to change this logo to something else.

I have:

1. run `find /usr/share -name "*logo*"` and suffixed all the CentOS logo looking icons with ".old" (to make sure they aren't found)
2. run `gtk-update-icon-cache`

...but the CentOS logo to the left of Applications will simply not disappear.

Does anyone which image needs to be replaced in order to change this logo to one of my choosing?

Answer (score 0):

The required file is:

> /usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/start-here.svg